# MySQL query with GROUPBY failing after years of use

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables, `expense` and `user`. The `expense` table is:

```
EXPENSE
id, int(11)
cost, double
category_fk, int(11)
date_time, datetime
comment, varchar(1000)
user_fk, int(11)
```

For about four years, I've been using the following SQL query to group expenses for a single user by month and to report the total expenses per month:

```sql
SELECT
  MONTH(date_time),
  YEAR(date_time),
  SUM(cost)
FROM expense
JOIN `user`
  ON `user`.id = expense.user_fk
WHERE `user`.id = 1234
GROUP BY
  date_time,
  MONTH(`date_time`),
  YEAR(`date_time`)
ORDER BY `date_time` ASC
```

Now, this query no longer works. In particular, the query does not `GROUPBY` correctly. Instead, each transaction is returned without a sum for the month.

The only thing that has changed is that locally, I upgraded MySQL because I have a new MacOS. However, this is for a web app, and the MySQL version did not, at least to my knowledge, change on the server, although it could have because it is a shared hosting service.

I have no mental model of what might be causing this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: So this fails on the server, and you have not upgraded the server? Did you check the MySQL version that is running on the server

Comment: I think you may need to go back and review years of data :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY date_time` makes it to return each row separately, as I believe each row has unique `date_time` value, so no grouping is happenning. Try to change it to

```sql
GROUP BY
  MONTH(`date_time`),
  YEAR(`date_time`)
```

And it should work